# Passing a c++ std::vector<Struct> to Qt python

Tags: python, c++, c, qt, struct

I'm developing a little Qgis plugin in Python. This plugin loads a C++ Dll and uses its methods. Now one of this methods returns a `std::vector<Struct>`, and I don't know how to handle it in Python. I read a lot of StackOverflow questions but I couldn't find any solution. I'm using Python 2.7 embedded in qgis developer (OSGeo) and pyqt4 for the GUI.

The method signature is:

```
extern "C"{
    __declspec(dllexport)  std::vector<MyStruct> loadValues();
}
```

The Struct declaration is:

```
struct MyStruct{
    std::string str1;
    std::string str2;
    std::string str3;
};
```

And the Python code is:

```
 mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('mydll.dll')
 array = []
 array = mydll.loadValues()
```

Would anybody help me?

Comment: I think `ctypes` if for c libraries, c++ libraries are complicated because of function overloading, and classes methods cannot be loaded with `dlopen()`, so it's a c only thing. You can always write a c or c++ module for python.

Comment: Seriously, a DLL shouldn't be returning STL types, or any type that manages dynamic memory.  Doesn't matter if it's Python or not.  Many reasons why, with the most prevalent being that you have to ensure that the caller is using the **exact** same implementation of `vector`, uses the same heap that the vector uses, etc..

Comment: Your best bet would be to use a C style array and load/unload that into a vector in a C++ wrapper.  Since vector has an internal structure which is implementation specific, its unlikely you could use ctypes with it.

Comment: @cdarke, IMO the best bet would be to use SWIG (http://www.swig.org/) or similar, write a C wrapper around the C++ code, and return a Python `list` to the calling Python code.

Comment: I don't understand why you first want to use SWIG and then write a C wrapper, @AndrewHenle. I'm not that familiar with SWIG (I know Boost.Python though) but it should be enough to just use that to create a Python module from the C++ DLL.

Comment: @AndrewHenle:  yes, you might be right, SWIG does support vectors to Python.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - I'd use a C interface because C++ name-mangling is non-portable.  There needs to be _something_ between the C++ method that returns a `std::vector<struct>` and Python, and IMO the simpler the better.  And C is a lot simpler than C++.  And I do realize it has to  be compiled with a C++ compiler to interface with C++ objects.  Just declare the interface methods as `extern "C"` to lose any name mangling.

Comment: I'd say the less there is between Python's C API and the C++ library, the better. Also, you can "naturally" return a vector from a C++ function that is then very simply forwarded to Python using Boost.Python. Since you need a matching C++ compiler to use the C++ library anyway (name-mangling actually protects you to some extent from using an incompatible one, btw), adding a detour to C is IMHO superfluous.

Comment: Thank everybody, you gave me a lot of usefull suggestons, and you answered so quickly.

Comment: Thank everybody, you gave me a lot of usefull suggestons, and you answered so quickly. But i don't have any experience with the solutions you pourposed, like SWIG or C-Wrapper or Boost.python. @ Andrew Henle, my methods are already intefaced with extern "C".

A possible solution i thought about was to change my method, passing by reference 3 arrays of strings, populating them in the c++ method and in python populate my array of structs. 
Something like this: 
''

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html - depending on the system you are on, installing the necessary code is just a simple "apt-get install libboost-dev".